# Why did this strange thing happen to my calculation?

Tags: equation-solving, replacement

I have a function of `r` given by `x[r_]=(2/r^2 + (1/r^2 - r/8)/r) (1 - 1/r - r^2/16)`. It is easy to check that this function has a root at `3.35026174113329222592483347398228943347930908203125`, and also, it is positive before this root. But when I replace `r` with a smaller number, say `3.35026174113329222592483347398228943341`, the result is negative (`x[r]=-2.213207274851646704854996448632632379535861132113534061049975321111560333520174026489257812500000000*10^-18`)!

Here is the code

```
Quit[]
myPrecision = 100;
y[r_] = 1 - 1/r - (r/4)^2;
x[r_] = y[r] (2/r^2 + D[y[r], r]/r);
Plot[x[r], {r, 0, 5}]
SetPrecision[FindRoot[x[r], {r, 3.35}], myPrecision]
SetPrecision[N[x[r] /. r -> 
3.35026174113329222592483347398228943341`100],100]
```

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform I added the code.

Comment: the root you give in line 3 is wrong. The right root is `{r -> 3.350261741133292141779243596300120961616} ` .

Comment: When you first calculate FindRoot with MachinPrecision and then set precision to 100, you generate wrong artificial digits.

Comment: Simply use WorkingPrecision and PrecicionGoal in FindRoot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your original root was a bit too large (the difference is of order `10^-17`). `SetPrecision[t,100]` cannot increase the accuracy of a result already generated. It just tells the kernel that this number `t` should be treated *as if* this would be precise up to 100 digits (i.e. it will try to preserve the accuracy of around 100 digits in further calculations).

This is how you get the root with 100 digits of precision:

```
myPrecision = 100;
y[r_] = 1 - 1/r - (r/4)^2; 
x[r_] = y[r] (2/r^2 + D[y[r], r]/r);
sol = FindRoot[x[r], {r, 3.35}, WorkingPrecision -> myPrecision]
x[r] /. sol
```

> 0.*10^-101

Answer (score 3):

```
x[r_] = (2/r^2 + (1/r^2 - r/8)/r) (1 - 1/r - r^2/16) // Simplify

(* ((-8 - 16 r + r^3) (16 - 16 r + r^3))/(128 r^4) *)
```

The exact solutions can be obtained with `Solve` and are expressed as `Root` objects

```
sol = Solve[x[r] == 0, r, Reals];
```

Verifying,

```
x[r] /. sol // RootReduce

(* {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0} *)
```

The approximate numeric values are

```
sol // N

(* {{r -> -3.72161}, {r -> -0.508203}, {r -> 4.22982}, {r -> -4.42864}, {r -> 
   1.07838}, {r -> 3.35026}} *)
```

You are interested in the last result.

```
soln = sol[[-1]] // N[#, 100] &

(* {r -> 3.3502617411332921417792435963001209616160650553547454652243077396828840\
85980998639484412200063305554} *)

x[r] /. soln

(* 0.*10^-101 *)
```